# Picker With Dynamic List triggers onValueChange - React Native (Android)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a Picker whose list loads dynamically, based on what has previously been selected.  When I select a value from the list, I would like to move it to a different list and remove it from the options.  The issue is that when I select an option, every time the list is re-rendered due to the setState, it selects the topmost value, and fires the onValueChange for that value.  This causes every value to fire an event and empties the list every time.

I have tried separating the picker into its own component, I have tried it both with and without a default selected value, I've set the selected value to be the topmost value, null, undefined, you name it.  I cannot figure out how to prevent this event from firing when I reload the list.

Take the [following demo app](https://rnplay.org/apps/4UMQCw), for example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Picker,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Sandbox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [
        {id: 1, title: "One"},
        {id: 2, title: "Two"},
        {id: 3, title: "Three"},
        {id: 4, title: "Four"},
      ],
      selected: []
    };
  }

  updateLists(id) {
    var list = this.state.list;
    var selected = this.state.selected
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var obj = list[i];
      if(obj.id == id) {
        selected.push(obj);
        list.splice(i, 1)
      }
    }

    this.setState({ list: list, selected: selected });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Picker
          onValueChange={(id) => {
            this.updateLists(id);
          }}>
          {this.state.list.map((item, index) => {
                return <Picker.Item key={index} label={item.title} value={item.id} />
            })}
        </Picker>
        <Text>{this.state.selected.toString()}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Sandbox', () => Sandbox);
```

Selecting any value from that list will trigger the `updateLists()` method for every value until they are all removed.  Using the attached RN Play link, I've found that this appears to be an Android only issue.  iOS works (mostly) fine.

Comment: To get a better clarification, are you trying to create a similar concept of multilple select where you can add and remove values from either side? Not saying that is what you are do but it sounds the same

Comment: @DrMints In this particular case, I am setting up a mailing list of sorts.  The user is able to select from a list of people with emails that will then populate a second list detailing who the email will go out to.  When an item is selected, I want to remove it from the Picker and move it to the listing.  This is all handled by API calls in my actual app, but the demo I've provided duplicates the functionality.  I have attached an RN Play link to the Sandbox code provided.

Comment: wanted to ask one thing, when you select anything from the list, then you want to remove that from the list, after that what you want to show selected in the list ??

Comment: @MayankShukla Sorry for the confusion.  Two lists:  One in the Picker that I am selecting from, one static representing values which I have already selected.  When I select an object, I want to remove it from the Picker and add it to the static list.

Comment: ah okay, in the word of programming our thoughts can go many ways that cleared it up for me

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @CaseyGarland Sort of.  I submitted an issue to the React Native team on Github, but they have not fixed it as of today.  In the meantime, I instead made the onValueChange update my state variable for the selected value and added a submit button to call the submit action, rather than the on change.